# Ceph requires at least 1 OSD(s) to store data

Tags: ansible, rhel, ceph, rhel8

After probing my nodes I can't seem to proceed to the Networks section of the installation process of `cockpi-ceph-installer` on the UI interface.
This is the error being thrown:

```sh
Ceph requires at least 1 OSD(s) to store data
```

I've already provisioned 3 nodes for my osds. I am currently using RHEL 8 instances

Comment: What is the `ceph status`? You need to provide more information, otherwise we can just guess. You'll need to figure out why there aren't any OSDs.

Answer (score 0):

check how many passthrough data disks are present on each one the 3 nodes you had provisioned. OSD Role expects atleast 1 physical disk present on your OSD Node (Non-OS Disk without any FS/LVM on top of it)